# Calculate $\exp \left[\begin{smallmatrix} 4 & 3 \\ -1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

> Given $$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 3  \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $$ how do I calculate $e^A$?

---

I know the following formula:

If $X$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix with trace $0$, then
$$e^X = \cos{\sqrt{\det(X)}} I_2 + \dfrac{\sin{\sqrt{\det(X)}}}{\sqrt{\det(X)}} X$$
Where we interpret the coeffficient of $X$ is $1$ if $\det(X)=0$.

The hint that i got in order to calculate $e^A$ is to reduce the calculation to the case with trace $0$. I dont know how to do that ( to reduce the calculation to the traceless case). Can anyone please help, I cannot proceed.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @ Saad okay I'll provide more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One result that will get you the final part of the way it's the following:

> If $M$ and $N$ are square matrices that commute, then$$e^{M+N}=e^Me^N$$

And since any matrix commutes with multiples of the identity, can you think of a way to write $A$ as the sum of a traceless matrix and a multiple of the identity matrix?

Comment: Thankyou so much, I think $A$ can be written as $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} $.

Comment: @Uncool That looks like a useful decomposition.

Comment: Yes you ignited me. Thankyou, By the way in what way you find this decomposition useful.

Comment: @Uncool As in, that looks like a decomposition that will help you solve your problem. I'm just being more obtuse than necessary.